# getting empty object on req.body when use formData to append data on frontend in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, form-data

i worked with formData before and it worked fine now when i try to send data to backend and console.log(req.body) it gives empty object but when i create an object and add properties it works fine

**here is front-end code**

```
const moveToSender = () => {
    let  formDatas = new FormData();

    formDatas.append("username",username);
    formDatas.append("email",email);
    formDatas.append("amount",amount);
    formDatas.append("reciever",reciever);
    formDatas.append("currency",currency);

    // for (var pair of fData.entries()) {
    //     console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
    // }

     sendAxiosPostRequest(formDatas);
  };

  const sendAxiosPostRequest = async (formDatas) => {
    
    // for (var pair of fData.entries()) {
    //     console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
    // }

   try {
     
const data = await axios.post("/addtransaction/newTransaction",formDatas,{
  headers:{
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
  }
})

console.log(data)


   } catch (error) {
     
   }
  };
```

Comment: `"Content-Type":"application/json"` seems odd here. You might wanna use `"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` instead

Comment: @mmoehrlein its not working

Comment: You could also try `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`. If that does not work, it would be great if you could provide the backend code as well

Comment: @mmoehrlein yess i have been doing it the same way but dont know wht its not working this time i tried all methods including multipart

Comment: @mmoehrlein okay kindly check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69427326/formdata-sending-empty-object-to-backend-from-front-end-using-react-and-axios-li

Comment: @mmoehrlein the most unusual thing is that when i used express-fileupload package it started to wrok , i am curious because file upload package deals with files what it has to do with formData